# Access Method in a Layout component

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, blazor

I have a method with 3 parameters in the layout. How can I call the function in the load event of a page which is using the layout.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
@code {

    private string x;
    public void Test (string a , string b, string c)
    {
        x = a + b + c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Refactor your code by extracting you method in a service you share between page

Answer (score 2):

```
<CascadingValue Value="this" Name="MainLayout">
    @Body
</ CascadingValue>
```

then in your component

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "MainLayout")]
    public MainLayout MainLayout { get; set; }

    void Test (string a , string b, string c) => MainLayout.Test(a, b, c);
}
```

Here is an example [component](https://github.com/BrianLParker/CleanView/blob/master/CleanView/CleanView/BackgroundSetter.razor) where I am doing something similar.